# Prove that $\dfrac{g(x,u_{n})}{\left\Vert u_{n}\right\Vert ^{p-1}}\rightarrow g_{0}$ weakly in $L^{\overline{p}}$ for some $\overline{p}>p*'$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega
 \subset
  \mathbb{R}^{N}$
  be a smooth bounded domain , $g:\Omega\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
  is a Caratheodory function such that $g(x,t)=0$
  for $t\leq0$
 . Suppose that there exist function $a\in L^{r}$
  and $d\in L^{p'}$
  such that

$\left|g(x,t)\right|\leq a(x)t^{p-1}+d(x)$

with $r>N/p$
  if $1<p\leq N$
  and $r=1$
  if $p>N$
 ; $p'$
  is Holder conjugate of $p$

Let $\left\{ u_{n}\right\} \subset W_{0}^{1,p}$
  be a sequence such that $\left\Vert u_{n}\right\Vert \rightarrow\infty$
  as $n\rightarrow\infty$
 . Let us define $v_{n}=u_{n}/\left\Vert u_{n}\right\Vert $
 . Hence $\left\Vert v_{n}\right\Vert =1$
  and we may assume that $v_{n}\rightarrow v$
  weakly in $W_{0}^{1,p}$
 . Prove that $\dfrac{g(x,u_{n})}{\left\Vert u_{n}\right\Vert ^{p-1}}\rightarrow g_{0}$
  weakly in $L^{\overline{p}}$
  for some $\overline{p}>p*'$
  if $p<N$
  and $\overline{p}=1$
  if $p\geq N$
 .

Here are my efforts:

Firstly consider $p<N$
  , my intension is: prove that $\dfrac{g(x,u_{n})}{\left\Vert u_{n}\right\Vert ^{p-1}}$
  is bounded in $L^{\overline{p}}$
  for some $\overline{p}>p*'$

$\dfrac{g(x,u_{n})}{\left\Vert u_{n}\right\Vert ^{p-1}}\leq a(x)\left|v_{n}\right|^{p-1}+\dfrac{d(x)}{\left\Vert u_{n}\right\Vert ^{p-1}}$

${\displaystyle \int_{\Omega}}\left|a(x)\left|v_{n}\right|^{p-1}\right|^{\delta}dx\leq{\displaystyle \int_{\Omega}}\left|a(x)\right|^{\delta}\left|v_{n}\right|^{(p-1)\delta}dx$

$\leq\left\Vert a(x)^{\delta}\right\Vert _{L^{\frac{N}{p\delta}}}\left\Vert \left|v_{n}\right|^{(p-1)\delta}\right\Vert _{L^{\frac{N}{N-p\delta}}}$

$\leq\left\Vert a(x)^{\delta}\right\Vert _{L^{\frac{N}{p\delta}}}\left\Vert v_{n}\right\Vert _{L^{\frac{N(p-1)\delta}{N-p\delta}}}^{(p-1)\delta}$

I expect that by Sobolev embedding, $\left\Vert a(x)^{\delta}\right\Vert _{L^{\frac{N}{p\delta}}}\left\Vert v_{n}\right\Vert _{L^{\frac{N(p-1)\delta}{N-p\delta}}}^{(p-1)\delta}\leq C\left\Vert a(x)^{\delta}\right\Vert _{L^{\frac{N}{p\delta}}}\left\Vert v_{n}\right\Vert ^{(p-1)\delta}=C\left\Vert a(x)^{\delta}\right\Vert _{L^{\frac{N}{p\delta}}}$
 , so we are done.

Thus we have to pick $\delta$
  such that ${\displaystyle \frac{N(p-1)\delta}{N-p\delta}}<\dfrac{Np}{N-p}
 \Longleftrightarrow\delta<\dfrac{pN}{Np-N+p}=p*'$

My trouble is when choose $\overline{p}=\delta$
 , we are done that $\dfrac{g(x,u_{n})}{\left\Vert u_{n}\right\Vert ^{p-1}}$
  is bounded in $L^{\overline{p}}$
  with $\overline{p}<p*'$
  (not $\overline{p}>p*'$
  ). On the other hand if choose $\overline{p}'=\delta$
 , we are done that $\overline{p}>p*'$
  but $\dfrac{g(x,u_{n})}{\left\Vert u_{n}\right\Vert ^{p-1}}$
  is bounded in $L^{\overline{p}'}$
  , not $L^{\overline{p}}$
  .

Please help me to take out that trouble. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Where do you got this problem?